# Error Message: 8 byte discriminator did not match what was expected

Tags: anchor

I have created an instruction and I am getting this error I have checked the account and it exists and this account has been already created with anchor before.
[image]

Comment: Kindly make your question more comprehensive by providing code samples showing the affected instructions, validators and accounts. As it is, an answer to your question would have to heavily rely on guesswork.

Comment: Please provide more code sample, however this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70484086/what-is-custom-program-error-0xa2-in-anchor might solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this error is i was passing an account which was a different type.